# format print in python

Tags: python, string, format

I want to know if there's way to do this:

```
printf("address is %x", address)
```

in Python. That is to integrate special strings that control the format of a output string. Thanks.

Comment: The Python docs cover this in great detail. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `%` operator. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) for details.

```
address = 16
print "address is %x" % address
```

Answer (score 1):

The modern and preferred<sup>1</sup> way to perform string formatting operations is to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print "address is {:x}".format(address)
```

Although the [`hex` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) works equally well in this case:

```
# [2:] removes the leading '0x'
print "address is", hex(address)[2:]
```

---

<sup>1</sup>For those who would like a citation, here is a note  from the [documentation for `%` formatting](https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting-operations):

> The formatting operations described here are obsolete and may go away
>   in future versions of Python. Use the new String Formatting in new
>   code.